# Same like TableAdapterManager in HTML 5 world

Tags: extjs, asp.net-web-api, wcf-data-services, kendo-asp.net-mvc, jaydata

To develop any document such as an Invoice or an Order, we need a master detail relationship. It looks like one to many relation.

Before we create a DataSet in ADO.net and Merge related tables modify them, then send them in SOAP XML over wcf to the server, make some business logic and say UpdateAll(DS) to the TableAdapterManager. It is updated in **one transaction to persist the changes to SQL Server**. We can compress, encrypt the message in WCF and it is done very fast and perfectly.

Now, the world changed. To develop such scenario in HTML5, We have **limited choices**:

- JayData or ExtJS that have an in-memory data source and data context.
- and Wcf Data Service OData with Patch update to Entity Framework on the server.
- then we override the dbContext.SaveChanges to manipulate the business logic.

WEP API does not have a patch update to JSON yet. Am I correct?

Are there any other choices that I can simulate the TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll while developing an HTML 5 application.

My question is constructive but I wish someone could put me on proper track on developing a form such as an invoice which has a one header and may rows and to be saved in one transaction then add the business logic in my server for the whole transaction.

I am not limited to any technology or tools from Microsoft or other. I want my HTML 5 form to be developed as I descried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $batch feature of OData could meet your requirement quite well. 
For the front end you can use JayData or Breeze
For the back end, just use WebApi OData 
Here is an example for it:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v3/ODataBatchSample/ODataBatchSample/

The latest version of OData is V4. Though it is for OData v3, it is a good start point. Also there will be such sample for V4 soon.